# Calling functions once class 'og-expanded' exists with jQuery Elastic Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-backstretch, elastic-grid

I'm using the plugin http://demo.phapsu.com/jquery.elastic_grid/ for a portfolio and also using jQuery backstretch plugin (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) with it on the `<section>` I have the portfolio in. When a portfolio item is clicked on and the portfolio item opens up, backstretch doesn't update. What I'm wanting to do, is call backstretch to update once the portfolio item has expanded (the class 'og-expanded' is present) and then also call backstretch again to update when the expanded item is closed.

I tried to invoke backstretch by calling `$("#portfolio").backstretch("resize");` within the code found here: [Forking elastic grid plugin to be able to close preview by clicking anywhere on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145402/forking-elastic-grid-plugin-to-be-able-to-close-preview-by-clicking-anywhere-on/31613844#31613844) which was a solution to allow a user to close the portfolio item when clicking anywhere outside of the portfolio popup, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help, hints, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.